# ExtJS - DWR proxy with json store?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, extjs, dwr

I'm trying to make a `JsonStore` use a function that takes arguments and executes asynchronously, but I'm not sure how to do this.

`myMethod` takes a `callback`, but how do I tie the callback data to the `JsonStore`?

```
store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    proxy: new Ext.data.DirectProxy(
    {
        directFn:(new function(){return MyDwrService.myMethod('test')}),
    }),
    autoLoad:true,...
```

I tried using a `DwrProxy` implementation, but now when I don't pass `fields` to `JsonReader`, no data populates my grid, and when I *do* pass `fields`, a bunch of blank rows are created. What gives?

```
   store = new Ext.data.Store({
        proxy: new Ext.ux.data.DwrProxy({
            apiActionToHandlerMap:{
                read: {
                    dwrFunction: MyService.myMethod,
                    getDwrArgsFunction: function() {
                        return ["testUser"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }),
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({fields:myFields}),
        autoLoad:true,
    fields:myFields,
    remoteSort:true
});
```

Comment: Can you post the json data you are getting after loading the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DWR3` with `JSONP` enabled and you won't need a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to include fields in the reader but I don't understand why there are blank rows. I'm pretty sure we don't get any empty records - maybe the allowBlank:false sorts it out.. if it's any use, this is our code:

```
var myReader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    root : 'objectsToConvertToRecords',
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields : [
        {name: 'id', allowBlank:false},
        {name: 'foo', allowBlank:false},
        {name: 'bar', allowBlank:false}
    ]
});

var dwrProxy = new Ext.ux.data.DwrProxy({
    apiActionToHandlerMap : {
        read : {
            dwrFunction : RemoteClass.remoteReadMethod,
            getDwrArgsFunction: function(request, newData, oldData) {
                return [request.params.myId];
            }
        }
        create : {
            dwrFunction : RemoteClass.remoteCreateMethod,
            getDwrArgsFunction: function(request, newData, oldData) {
                return [newData];
            }
        }
        update : {
            dwrFunction : RemoteClass.remoteUpdateMethod,
            getDwrArgsFunction: function(request, newData, oldData) {
                return [newData];
            }
        }
        destroy : {
            dwrFunction : RemoteClass.remoteDestroyMethod
        }
    }
});

var store = new Ext.data.Store({
     proxy: dwrProxy,
    reader: myReader,
    writer : myWriter,
    autoLoad : true,
    autoSave: true,
    baseParams: { tiploc: this.tiploc }
})
```